# When clicking play button doesn't moves to next screen

Tags: javascript, html, button, screen

So I was making a code to make a game in which a screen appears wit ha play game button when we click on the button it  redirects us to the next screen but that's not working. I have posted all the code I have written till now and this is not fully completed but enough to get the next screen after clicking play game button.*

```
            *HTML***strong text**
```

```js
let score=0
let selected_agent={}
start_btn.addEventListener('click',() =>screens[0].classList.add('up'))

choose_game_btn.forEach(btn=>{
    btn.addEventListener('click',()=> {
        const img = btn.querySelector('img')
        const src = img.getAttribute('src')
        const alt = img.getAttribute('alt')
        selected_agent = {src, alt}
        screens[1].classList.add('up')
        setTimeout(createAgent,1000)
        startGame()

    })
})
function  CreateInsect(){
    const agent=document.createElement('div')
        .agent.classList.add('agent')
    const{x,y}=getRandomLocation()
    agent.style.top='${y}px'
    agent.style.left='${y}px'
    agent.innerHTML='<img src="${selected_agent.src}" alt="${selected_agent.alt}"style="transform: rotate(${Math.random' +
        '()*360}deg)" />'
    game_container.appendChild(agent)
    agent.
}
function getRandomLocation(){
    const width=window.innerWidth
    const height=window.innerHeight
    const x=Math.random()*(width-200)+100
     const y=Math.random()*(height-200)+100
    return{x,y}
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Press Start 2p",sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
{  color:#fff;
}
h1{
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.btn {

    border: 0;
    background-color: white;
    color: yellowgreen;
    padding: 15px 20px;
font-family: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:hover{
    opacity: 0.9%;
}
.btn:focus{
    outline:0;
}
.screen{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
   transition:margin 0.5s ease-out;
}


.Game-List{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap ;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;

}
.Game-List li{
    margin: 10px;
}

.choose-game-btn{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: inherit;

}
.choose-game-btn:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: #516dff;
}
.choose-game-btn:active{
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);

}
.choose-game-btn image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: contain;

}
.game-container{
    position: relative;

}
.time,.score{
    position:absolute ;
    top: 20px;

}
.time{
    left: 20px;
}
.score{
    right: 20px;
}
.message{
    line-height: 1.7;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-150%);
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in;
}
.message.visible{
    transform: translate(-50%,150%);
    opacity: 1;


}
.agent{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;

    transform: translate(-50-50) scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;

}
.agent.caught{
    transform: translate(-50-50) scale(0);
}
.agent img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

}
.screen.up{
   margin-top: -100vh ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="GAME.css">
    <script src="GAME.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>

    </title>

</head>

<body>


<div
    class="screen">
    <h1>Catch it</h1>
    <button class="btn" id="start-btn">Play Game</button>
</div>

<div class="screen">
<h1> What is ur FAVOURITE AGENT </h1>
<ul class="Game-List">
    <li>
        <button class="choose-game-btn">
            <img src="jett.png" alt="Jett" width="150" height="150"/>



        </button>


      </li>
    <li>
        <button class="choose-game-btn">
            <img src="raze.jpg"  alt="raze" width="150" height="150"/>



        </button>


      </li>
<li>
        <button class="choose-game-btn">
            <img src="yoru.jpg"  alt="yoru" width="150" height="150"/>



        </button>


      </li>
    <li>
        <button class="choose-game-btn">
            <img src="reyna.jpg" alt="reyna" width="150" height="150"/>




        </button>


      </li>
    <li>
        <button class="choose-game-btn">
            <img src="pheonix.jpg"  alt="phoenix" width="150" height="150"/>



        </button>


      </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<div
    class="screen game-container" id="game-container">
    <h3 id="time" class="time">class=00:00</h3>
    <h3 class="score" id="score">:0</h3>
    <h5 id="message" class="message visible">
        Keep doing till ur hands bends<br>
        If u win U win 1000000000$ so keep doing it until it says u did it

    </h5>




</div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
                                         *CSS*
            
            
            
            
            @
        
            import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');
                
                * {
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                }
                
                body{
                background-color: blue;
                    color: white;
                    font-family: "Press Start 2p",sans-serif;
                    height: 100vh;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    margin: 0;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                {  color:#fff;
                }
                h1{
                    line-height: 1.4;
                }
                .btn {
                
                    border: 0;
                    background-color: white;
                    color: yellowgreen;
                    padding: 15px 20px;
                font-family: inherit;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
                .btn:hover{
                    opacity: 0.9%;
                }
                .btn:focus{
                    outline:0;
                }
                .screen{
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: center;
                    height: 100vh;
                    width: 100vw;
                   transition:margin 0.5s ease-out;
                }
                
                
                .Game-List{
                    display: flex;
                    flex-wrap:wrap ;
                    justify-content: center;
                    list-style-type: none;
                    padding: 0;
                
                }
                .Game-List li{
                    margin: 10px;
                }
                
                .choose-game-btn{
                    background-color: transparent;
                    color: white;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    font-family: inherit;
                
                }
                .choose-game-btn:hover{
                    background-color: white;
                    color: #516dff;
                }
                .choose-game-btn:active{
                background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
                
                }
                .choose-game-btn image {
                    width: 100px;
                    height: 100px;
                    object-fit: contain;
                
                }
                .game-container{
                    position: relative;
                
                }
                .time,.score{
                    position:absolute ;
                    top: 20px;
                
                }
                .time{
                    left: 20px;
                }
                .score{
                    right: 20px;
                }
                .message{
                    line-height: 1.7;
                    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    width: 100%;
                    padding: 20px;
                    z-index: 100;
                    text-align: center;
                    opacity: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    top:0;
                    left:50%;
                    transform: translate(-50%,-150%);
                    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in;
                }
                .message.visible{
                    transform: translate(-50%,150%);
                    opacity: 1;
                
                
                }
                .agent{
                    cursor: pointer;
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: center;
                    width: 100px;
                    height: 100px;
                    position: absolute;
                
                    transform: translate(-50-50) scale(1);
                    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
                
                }
                .agent.caught{
                    transform: translate(-50-50) scale(0);
                }
                .agent img{
                    width: 100px;
                    height: 100px;
                
                }
                .screen.up{
                   margin-top: -100vh ;
                }
                                                 
        
        *JS*
            
        let score=0
        let selected_agent={}
        start_btn.addEventListener('click',() =>screens[0].classList.add('up'))
        
        choose_game_btn.forEach(btn=>{
            btn.addEventListener('click',()=> {
                const img = btn.querySelector('img')
                const src = img.getAttribute('src')
                const alt = img.getAttribute('alt')
                selected_agent = {src, alt}
                screens[1].classList.add('up')
                setTimeout(createAgent,1000)
                startGame()
        
            })
        })
        function  CreateInsect(){
            const agent=document.createElement('div')
                .agent.classList.add('agent')
            const{x,y}=getRandomLocation()
            agent.style.top='${y}px'
            agent.style.left='${y}px'
            agent.innerHTML='<img src="${selected_agent.src}" alt="${selected_agent.alt}"style="transform: rotate(${Math.random' +
                '()*360}deg)" />'
            game_container.appendChild(agent)
            agent.
        }
        function getRandomLocation(){
            const width=window.innerWidth
            const height=window.innerHeight
            const x=Math.random()*(width-200)+100
const y=Math.random()*(height-200)+100
return{x,y}
}
```

Comment: Sry i am new here so doesnt know how t o edit it but the first code is javascript and second is css and 3rd is html ignore the 4th one i repeated css again

Comment: Are you getting an error? Can you provide more details about your question

Comment: no it does not show nay error just not working and basically in css the .screen.up should change the screen so when i should change the value from -100 to -200 it should go to the next page but it doesnt work at all so i think the problem might not be in the button rather its in the screens maybe